# Error in strsplit(unitspec, " ") in code for Machine Learning for Hackers

Tags: r

I am new to this book and get an error with the example code for the first chapter. I installed the latest version of R 3.2.3 and RStudio. I installed package_install.R given by the sample code and then installed ggplot2 by myself. When I run the code ufo_sightings.R, I got an error as follow

```
`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
Error in strsplit(unitspec, " ") : non-character argument
In addition: Warning message:
Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin).
```

I am new to R so I have no idea what is wrong. Can anyone help? Is it because I used the latest version of R?

Edit: I think I found the reason. If I change ggplot to 1.01 version, it worked fine. If I upgrade it to 2.0.0 the error occurs. I guess it is a bug?

Comment: Possible reason - a new version of `ggplot2` just came out. See http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/12/21/ggplot2-2-0-0/

Comment: I tried to downgrade ggplot2, but it told me that ggplot2_1.0.1 is not available for R3.2.3. Now I tried to downgrade R to 3.2.2, but still got the same problem.

Comment: I have a copy of _Machine Learning for Hackers_ by Drew Conway and John Myles White, and I don't see the example you're citing in Chapter 1.  Can you confirm that I have the correct book and provide a page reference?

Comment: @Jubbles I think it's on page 19, in the section "Aggregating and organizing the data".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem lies in the ggplot function scale_x_date. In the original code this is coded as:

```
quick.hist <- ggplot(ufo.us, aes(x = DateOccurred)) +
  geom_histogram() + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = "50 years")
```

The breaks in scale_x_date has been adjusted to date_breaks. If you adjust the code to the following it works.

```
quick.hist <- ggplot(ufo.us, aes(x = DateOccurred)) +
  geom_histogram() + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "50 years", date_labels = "%Y")
```

In the rest of the code where you see ggplot and scale_x_date, you will have to adjust the breaks into date_breaks.

Comment: Why you cannot use `minor_breaks` there with `scale_x_date`?

Answer (score 0):

For me, both using the ggplot 1.0.1 version and adjusting the date_breaks for 10 years for DateReported while 50 years for DateOccured, works absolutely fine and generates a nice visualization.

```
quick.hist <- ggplot(ufo.us, aes(x = DateOccurred)) +
  geom_histogram() + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "50 years", date_labels = "%Y")

quick.hist <- ggplot(ufo.us, aes(x = DateReported)) +
  geom_histogram() + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "10 years", date_labels = "%Y")
```